# accessing objects from multiple threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm trying to make a simple audio delay effect by creating a number of threads. Each thread instantiates a SoundPool object and thus plays a copy the sound. The delay effect is obtained by using Thread.sleep(delayTime), where delayTime is conveniently setted at a different value for each thread, in order to delay the sound reproduction. I'm storing the created SoundPool objects into an array in order to manipulate them later (e.g. changing some parameter value).

I've tried to implement the threads in both ways (as a simple Thread or implementing Runnable), and both implementations present issues in accessing the SoundPool objects once they've been setted by the threads, which are presumably due to the locking of the object by its creating thread. The issues don't seem to occur when sharing a simple variable, though.

Simply put, I want to access publicly to an object which has been manipulated by a thread, and I don't know how to release the thread's lock over it.

Here's the code.

FIRST IMPLEMENTATION
The first implementation successfully creates the effect, but the SoundPool objects aren't accessible from outside the threads. For example I created a button whose click shoud pause the playing of all the sound copies.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
  public SoundPool soundCopies[];
  int soundCopiesNumber = 6;
  double delayTimes[];
  double volumes[];
  int soundIds[];
  int streamIds[];   
  int copyIndex = 0;
  long delayTime = 0;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //other code

    final SoundPool[] soundCopies = new SoundPool[6];
    final int[] soundIds = new int[6];
    final int[] streamIds = new int[6];
    final double[] volumes = new double[6];
    double[] delayTimes = new double[6];

    //filling volumes[] and delayTimes[] with convenient values and other code

    //create a thread for each sound copy
    for (int i = 0; i<soundCopiesNumber; i++ ){
       copyIndex = i;
       delayTime = (long)delayTimes[i];
       new Thread(){
         public void run(){
        try {
        Thread.sleep(delayTime);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
         }
            //create a SoundPool
            soundCopies[copyIndex] = new SoundPool(6, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

            //other code related to the SoundPool managament, setting parameters 
            //such as volume and playing the sound

         }.start();
    }

//managing the button click in order to stop playing
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    switch (arg0.getId()) {

    //other code

    case R.id.delayStop:
        for (int i = 0; i<soundCopiesNumber; i++ ){
                try { 
            //pause the playing of each sound
            soundCopies[i].pause(streamIds[i]);
            } catch (Exception e){
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
            break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

}
```

The exception generated by clicking the button is:

```
W/System.err(31075): java.lang.NullPointerException

W/System.err(31075):    at com.example.soundpooltest.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:174)

W/System.err(31075):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)

W/System.err(31075):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)

W/System.err(31075):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)

W/System.err(31075):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

W/System.err(31075):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

W/System.err(31075):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)

W/System.err(31075):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

W/System.err(31075):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

W/System.err(31075):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)

W/System.err(31075):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)

W/System.err(31075):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

SECOND IMPLEMENTATION The second implementation uses Runnable to create an array of threads, but they don't even access the soundCopies array which is instantiated in the onCreate method (that is, on the main thread). If my first implementation is unviable for my purposes I will post that code too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To access one single object from multiple thread, you need some synchronized values.

Comment: @Veer: thanks for the advice, I'm trying to figure it out. If you would elaborate, or link to an example, it would be very appreciated. In the meanwhile I realized I don't really need the threads after they created the SoundPool objects, so is there a way to simply get rid of them and all their locks?